# Linked List - Object reference not set to instance of object

Tags: linked-list, null, object-reference

I'm writing a method that adds a new Node to the back of a linked list:

```
public void add(string title, string director, int year, double cost)
    {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.disc = new BluRayDisc(title, director, year, cost);

        Node holder = new Node();
        holder = first;
        while (holder.next != null)    //object reference error
        {
            holder = holder.next;
        }
        holder.next = newNode;
    }
```

but am getting a  "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"  error thrown.

The 'first' node is initialized to null so I'm assuming that's where my problem comes from.
This is my first linked list, and this follows the example of an addToBack method I was given exactly. Does anyone have some insight on this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues:

- `first` can be `null`, which is the case when you start with an empty linked list, and in that case `first.next` is an invalid reference.
- About: `Node holder = new Node();`. It is not necessary to create a new node here, with `new Node()`, since in the next statement, you are throwing away that node, by doing `holder = first;`

Here is the correction:

```
public void add(string title, string director, int year, double cost)
{
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.disc = new BluRayDisc(title, director, year, cost);

    if (first == null) {
        first = newNode;
        return;
    }
    holder = first;
    while (holder.next != null)    //object reference error
    {
        holder = holder.next;
    }
    holder.next = newNode;
}
```

Comment: Ahh that makes sense. Will this result in a duplicate of newNode when displaying all nodes, since I'm setting it as first and inserting it into the list?

Comment: No, the function exits after setting the first node reference to the new node, so it is at that moment the only node in the list. The next time you add a node, it will enter the while loop and add the new node after that existing node, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, the problem is that the variable "first" is initialized to null. It should be set the to the first node of the linked list you are constructing.